# Undefined citation but citation key exists in bib file

Tags: citing, overleaf

I'm writing my thesis on Overleaf but all citations result in the error:

```
You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. 
Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography,
and that both are spelled the same way.
```

I doubled checked that:

- The bib file is present
- The citation key exists in this file
- `\bibliography{...}` references this file in the `\begin{document}` environment

I isolated a minimal reproductible example and I tested it in a fresh Overleaf black project. There are two files at the root level: `main.tex` and `refs.bib`. The main file content is:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Test}
\author{Author}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\cite{redmonYOLO9000BetterFaster2017}

\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

And the reference corresponding to this key in the bibtex file:

```tex
@inproceedings{redmonYOLO9000BetterFaster2017,
  title = {{{YOLO9000}}: {{Better}}, {{Faster}}, {{Stronger}}},
  shorttitle = {{{YOLO9000}}},
  booktitle = {2017 {{IEEE Conference}} on {{Computer Vision}} and {{Pattern Recognition}} ({{CVPR}})},
  author = {Redmon, Joseph and Farhadi, Ali},
  year = {2017},
  month = jul,
  pages = {6517--6525},
  issn = {1063-6919},
  doi = {10.1109/CVPR.2017.690},
  abstract = {We introduce YOLO9000, a state-of-the-art, real-time object detection system that can detect over 9000 object categories. First we propose various improvements to the YOLO detection method, both novel and drawn from prior work. The improved model, YOLOv2, is state-of-the-art on standard detection tasks like PASCAL VOC and COCO. Using a novel, multi-scale training method the same YOLOv2 model can run at varying sizes, offering an easy tradeoff between speed and accuracy. At 67 FPS, YOLOv2 gets 76.8 mAP on VOC 2007. At 40 FPS, YOLOv2 gets 78.6 mAP, outperforming state-of-the-art methods like Faster RCNN with ResNet and SSD while still running significantly faster. Finally we propose a method to jointly train on object detection and classification. Using this method we train YOLO9000 simultaneously on the COCO detection dataset and the ImageNet classification dataset. Our joint training allows YOLO9000 to predict detections for object classes that dont have labelled detection data. We validate our approach on the ImageNet detection task. YOLO9000 gets 19.7 mAP on the ImageNet detection validation set despite only having detection data for 44 of the 200 classes. On the 156 classes not in COCO, YOLO9000 gets 16.0 mAP. YOLO9000 predicts detections for more than 9000 different object categories, all in real-time.},
  keywords = {COCO detection dataset,Detectors,Favorite,Feature extraction,image classification,Image resolution,ImageNet classification dataset,ImageNet detection task,object classification,object detection,Object detection,object detection system,Paper 1,PASCAL VOC,Real-time systems,Training,YOLO detection method,YOLO9000,YOLOv2 model}
}
```

the compiler is pdfLaTeX.

Comment: you are missing a `\bibliographystyle` command. Doesn't overleaf report an error from bibtex?

Comment: No other error except a `Underfull \hbox` no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a bibliography style seems to fix the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Test}
\author{Author}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\cite{redmonYOLO9000BetterFaster2017}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue in my original project. It looks like my other projects include custom styles so `\bibliographystyle` wasn't needed in them.

Comment: @LouisLac, Good to know that! Perhaps you can accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and the accepted answer did not work for me. For those that ended up here and unable to solve it, it is still the issue of a missing bibliography style, but this time, latex could not find the bibliography style file. Running `bibtex file` should reveal the issue. I found out that:

- either the custom bibliography style `bst` is missing
- or, the style is part of a package like `natbib`.

Switching to another style that I knew is installed worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch thank you!

Comment: Huh, so it is. This worked for me. Thank you!